# SWUpdate use copy-handler from Yocto meta-swupdate layer

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, swupdate

Trying to copy `/etc/machine-id` from one partition to another using SWUpdate.

When running the .swu update I get the error `ERROR : feature 'copy' required for '' in sw-description is absent!`

I guess I'm supposed to modify `swupdate_%.bbappend` on Yocto, but I'm not sure what to add to the `DEPENDS` ?

Modified the `sw-description` to use the [SWUpdate copy-handler](https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/handlers.html#copy-handler)

```
scripts : (
    {
    device = "/dev/mmcblk0p3";
    type = "copy";
    properties : {
            copyfrom = "/etc/machine-id";
            type = "postinstall";
            chain = "raw";
            create-destination = "true";
            }
    }
);
```

Log:

```
[add_properties] : Found properties for :
[add_properties_cb] : Property copyfrom: /etc/machine-id
[add_properties_cb] : Property type: postinstall
[add_properties_cb] : Property chain: raw
[add_properties_cb] : Property create-destination: true
[_parse_scripts] : Found Script:
[_parse_bootloader] : Bootloader var: swupdateboot = /dev/mmcblk0p3
ERROR : feature 'copy' required for '' in sw-description is absent!
ERROR : Compatible SW not found
ERROR : Writing to IPC fails due to Broken pipe
Image invalid or corrupted. Not installing ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an older version of SWUpdate without the copy-handler support. Need to upgrade the `meta-swupdate` layer to a more recent version and in run `bitbake -c menuconfig swupdate` and enable Copy Handler so that defconfig has "CONFIG_COPY=y".